# which of toolbox use for event keypressed in framework .net c++

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I am not sure what of toolbox(button) I have to use for event keypressed

Comment: be specific. your question will be deleted in minutes if you don't elaborate it.

Answer (score 1):

Click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Double-click KeyPressed to add an event handler.